# Qt C++ Missing DLLs

Tags: c++, qt

I created a simple notepad file using Qt.

The program does run when in Qt creator.

However, when I navigate to the debug folder, the created executable file does not run without DLLs.

I've read online that this is can happen and all that is required is that the respective DLLs be copied to the location of the exe file. However... the error messages identify DLLs that my machine does not have.

I get and error message for the following DLL files.

Qt5Cored.dll, Qt5Widgetsd.dll, QtPrintSupportd.dll

I do not have the DLLs above. I do however have the dll files below. Which do not have the added 'd' before the extension.

Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll, QtPrintSupport.dll

Any help provided would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You compiled a debug release (marked by the "d" suffix in your DLL names). The Qt directory should contain the debug libraries as well. Or you could build in release mode...

Comment: This is normal and you can find how to deploy the Qt Windows application with windeployqt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html So, why would you expect to have all components in the build directory?

Answer (score 1):

First i can't think of any reason you would want to copy (preparing for an installer) the dependencies for the `debug` build of your application, the debug is not a build that you want to deploy, use the `release` build for deployment.

Now, that being said, you definitely have the dll's, otherwise your `debug` build won't run from Qt Creator, you are just not looking in the right path for those dlls.

The path where you find the dll is something like: `C:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\bin`
notice that there can be many Qt versions installed and for different targets (example android), so the right way to find the dlls is: `QT_INSTALL_PATH / QT_VERSION / COMPILER_VERSION _ARCHITECTURE / bin`, so the sample path i provided is Qt version 5.12.3 build with Visual Studio 2017's compiler and it is a 64 bit build. In that path you will find the right dlls: Qt5Core.dll (the release build), Qt5Core**d**.dll (debug) and so on for all the Qt modules.

Side note: you most likely looked into the folder where Qt Creator .exe is located, there you will find only the Qt dlls that are needed for Qt Creator to work, you are not supposed to use those dlls to deploy your application (those might be built with a different compiler than what you are using and even  cause crashes for your application, because of incompatible abi)

Comment: Is there anyway to compile/ build the project so that all the dll files are embded in the exe file automatically?

Comment: Another question (apologizes), after copying all the relevant dlls (from the appropriate build folder) I still receive an error. The error is shown below.           "The procedure entry point ??0QPrintDialog@@QAE@PAVQPrinter@@PAVQWidget@@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\....project location"

Comment: Yes and no. No for the dlls (dynamic linkage), we also have static linkage (i'm just writeing keywords so that you can read more online), but for static linkage you need to build Qt yourself and there are license limitations if you use the open source Qt version (LGPL).

Comment: But for the dlls Qt has a tool called windeployqt, read more here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: The error probably means that you need to copy the print-support plugins, try to use the _windeployqt_ tool

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I will give windeployqt a try.